# Calculating total area of pie charts in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, equal-area, chart

Background: I am scaling the size of pie charts by a field which indicates a percentage. I am doing this for two datasets displayed on two maps and would like the resulting areas of the scaled pies to be equal between the two maps. I think that I would be able to do this by normalizing the scaled pie sizes using one of the two total areas of the pie charts.

Question: **Is it possible to find out the total area of the pies as they are displayed on the map?** I am able to scale the sizes manually for example, by setting a larger minimum size symbol, however it is difficult to visually gauge equal total areas this way.

Answer (score 0):

While I am unable to determine their areas to create a normalizing field, I was able to just add the percentages from one map's sizing percentage field to the other's and vice versa, such that the pies are now scaled in reference to each other (this way, the percentages were able to take each other into account and display the pies in proportion to all the pies between the two maps).